# Python converting waterfall figure to plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I am using the `waterfall_chart` package in Python to create a waterfall figure. The package mainly uses `matplotlib` in the backend, so I was trying to use the `tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)` function to covert the `matplotlib` figure into `plotly`. But when converting, an error pops up. Is there a way to convert `waterfall_chart` into `plotly` or is there an easy way to create the chart directly in `plotly`? I saw some previous discussion on similar [chart](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#waterfall-bar-chart) in `plotly`, but it involved pretty manual coding of the chart number.

You could use the following code to recreate the chart.

```
import waterfall_chart
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.tools as tls

a = ['sales','returns','credit fees','rebates','late charges','shipping']
b = [10,-30,-7.5,-25,95,-7]
mpl_fig = plt.figure()
waterfall_chart.plot(a, b)

plt.show()
```

[waterfall chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plcR5.png)

But when I try to convert to `plotly` using `mpl_to_plotly()`, there is an error:

```
plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

The detail of the `waterfall_chart` package could be found here: https://github.com/chrispaulca/waterfall/blob/master/waterfall_chart.py

Answer (score 0):

My answer addresses

> [...] or is there an easy way to create the chart directly in plotly?

---

**With newer versions of plotly you can use `plotly.graph_objs.Waterfall`.**

Below is a basic example with your data sample with a setup that uses `iplot` in an off-line Jupyter Notebook:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
import plotly
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:35% !important; } .widget-select > select {background-color: gainsboro;}</style>"))
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(1)

import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode(connected = False)

# your values
a = ['sales','returns','credit fees','rebates','late charges','shipping']
b = [10,-30,-7.5,-25,95,-7]

# waterfall trace
trace = go.Waterfall(
     x = a, 
    textposition = "outside", 
    text = [str(elem) for elem in b], 
    y = b, 
    connector = {"line":{"color":"rgb(63, 63, 63)"}}, 
)

layout = go.Layout(
        title = "Waterfall chart, plotly version 3.9.0", 
        showlegend = True
)

iplot(go.Figure([trace], layout))
```

---

Check your version with:

```
import plotly
plotly.__version__
```

Update your version in a cmd console using:

```
pip install plotly --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

List a has a length of 6, list b has a length of 5.
Matplotlib refuses to display an empty array, list or whatever.
Solve it to add a number or 0 to b or add an if to your code, to avoid matplotlib gets an empty sequence.